# How to write windows command output to a file?

Tags: java, io

Hi I am making a program in which I execute windows command and save it into file but i am confused how to write long data into a file..I did write the file but only contained last line.please help.

```
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig"); 
    p.waitFor(); 
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
    ); 
    String line=reader.readLine();

    while(line!=null) 
    { 
       System.out.println(line); 
       line=reader.readLine(); 
    }
```

Comment: what is your problem. your code good in console..

Comment: the problem is solved.I only wanted to write it in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig > filename.txt");
```

If all you want to do is get the output into a file, you might as well just add the command for it on the command line. If you want to read and parse it from your code, you will need a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you do in fact need to do something else with the results, you could do something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig"); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 

BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    File file = new File(filename);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        writer.write(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```